# Splitting data - specific case

Tags: python, string, date, python-3.x

I'm trying to split some data, the data is in this form...

```
['20150406,34.4800,34.8100,34.2300,34.4200,21480500', '20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200']
```

The first item in each string in the list is a date, I am trying split the data at a chosen date. But have the whole string... For example if my chosen date was 2015-04-07 the above data would split like this...

```
['20150406,34.4800,34.8100,34.2300,34.4200,21480500']

['20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200']
```

This also has to work for lists with lots of strings in the same form as this...

Comment: Can there be many dates the same? Can you add an example for multiple elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to find the position of the string with the desired date, then *slice*:

```
>>> d = '20150407'
>>> l = [
...     '20150406,34.4800,34.8100,34.2300,34.4200,21480500',
...     '20160402,34.1,32.8100,33.2300,31.01,22282510',
...     '20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200',
...     '20120101,2.540,14.8201,32.00,30.1311,12331230'
... ]
>>> index = next(i for i, item in enumerate(l) if item.startswith(d))
>>> l[:index]
['20150406,34.4800,34.8100,34.2300,34.4200,21480500', '20160402,34.1,32.8100,33.2300,31.01,22282510']
>>> l[index:]
['20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200', '20120101,2.540,14.8201,32.00,30.1311,12331230']
```

Couple notes:

- `next()` would through a `StopIteration` exception if there will be no match - you should either handle it with `try/except` or provide a default value, `-1` for example:

  ```
  next((i for i, item in enumerate(l) if item.startswith(d)), -1)
  ```
- to check if the date matches a desired one, we are simply checking if an item starts with a specific date string. If the desired date comes as a `date` or `datetime`, you would need to format it beforehand using `strftime()`:

  ```
  >>> from datetime import datetime
  >>> d = datetime(2015, 4, 7)
  >>> d = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")
  >>> d
  '20150407'
  ```

Comment: You can add a `","` to the string and it will match the exact substring

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a groupby, grouping strings that don't start with the date and ones that do so the date delimits the groups:

```
l = ['20150406,34.4800,34.8100,34.2300,34.4200,21480500', '2015010,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200'
    , '20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200']
dte = "2015-04-07"

delim = dte.replace("-","") + ","
from itertools import groupby

print([list(v) for k,v in groupby(l,key=lambda x: not x.startswith(delim))])

[['20150406,34.4800,34.8100,34.2300,34.4200,21480500', '2015010,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200'],   ['20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200']]
```

The groupby will keep splitting the data as many times as there are strings the start with the date.

Answer (score 1):

by extend from alecxe answer:
The code can split original list to couple sublist by input date.

```
l = [
...      '20150406,34.4800,34.8100,34.2300,34.4200,21480500',
...      '20160402,34.1,32.8100,33.2300,31.01,22282510',
...      '20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200',
...      '20120101,2.540,14.8201,32.00,30.1311,12331230',
...  '20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200',]

index = [i for i, item in enumerate(l) if item.startswith(d)]
[l[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+index, index+[None])]

output:
[['20150406,34.4800,34.8100,34.2300,34.4200,21480500', '20160402,34.1,32.8100,33.2300,31.01,22282510'], ['20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200', '20120101,2.540,14.8201,32.00,30.1311,12331230'], ['20150407,34.5400,34.8900,34.5100,34.6300,14331200']]
```